# QML Camera size issue

Tags: qt, camera, qml

I am facing an issue with image size when I pass the image from QML to Qt to perform some processing.

I have a `Camera` element and a `VideoOutput` element inside a QML document and I have a class that takes the Camera image to perform the changes in C++. This class is registered to be used with QML: `qmlRegisterType<processaImagem>("ProcessaImagemQml", 1, 0, "ProcessaImagem");` in main.cpp

Inside the processaImagem class I have a `Q_PROPERTY` called `tamanhoImagem` that holds the size of the image. The value of this property is defined inside the QML document `camera.tamanhoImagem = Qt.size(cameraView.sourceRect.width, cameraView.sourceRect.height);`

The problem is that the image size returned in QML is different than the same value passed to C++. In QML the result of `console.log("Tamanho da imagem: " + camera.tamanhoImagem);` is `320 x 240` and in C++ the result of `qDebug() << p_tamanhoImagem;` is `180 x 240`.

This problem just occurs when I run this code on a smartphone; on a desktop it runs without this problem.

Code below:

```
Camera {
    id: camera

    property string caminhoPreview: ""
    property size tamanhoImagem: Qt.size(0, 0);

    captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage

    imageCapture {
        onImageCaptured: {
            imagemPreview.source = preview;

            camera.caminhoPreview = preview;

            camera.tamanhoImagem = Qt.size(cameraView.sourceRect.width, cameraView.sourceRect.height);

            camera.stop();

            console.log("Tamanho da imagem: " + camera.tamanhoImagem);
        }
    }
}

VideoOutput {
    id: cameraView

    visible: true

    focus: visible

    anchors.fill: parent

    source: camera
    orientation: camera.orientation
    fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectFit
}

ProcessaImagem {
    id: processaImagem

    caminhoImagem: camera.caminhoPreview
    tamanhoImagem: camera.tamanhoImagem

    onCaminhoImagemChanged: {
        ProvedorImagem.carregaImagem(processaImagem.carregaImagem());
    }
}
```

processaimagem.h

```
class processaImagem : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString caminhoImagem READ caminhoImagem WRITE setCaminhoImagem NOTIFY caminhoImagemChanged)

    Q_PROPERTY(QSize tamanhoImagem READ tamanhoImagem WRITE setTamanhoImagem NOTIFY tamanhoImagemChanged)

public slots:
    QImage carregaImagem();

public:
    processaImagem(QObject *parent = 0);

    QString caminhoImagem() const;
    void setCaminhoImagem(const QString valor);

    QSize tamanhoImagem() const;
    void setTamanhoImagem(const QSize valor);

private:
    QString p_caminhoImagem = "";        
    QSize p_tamanhoImagem = QSize(0, 0);

signals:
    void caminhoImagemChanged();
    void tamanhoImagemChanged();
};
```

processaimagem.cpp

```
processaImagem::processaImagem(QObject *parent)
{

}

QImage processaImagem::carregaImagem()
{
    QUrl caminhoImagem(p_caminhoImagem);
    QQmlEngine *engine = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
    QQmlImageProviderBase *imageProviderBase = engine->imageProvider(caminhoImagem.host());
    QQuickImageProvider *imageProvider = static_cast<QQuickImageProvider*>(imageProviderBase);

    QString imageId = caminhoImagem.path().remove(0, 1);
    QImage imagem = imageProvider->requestImage(imageId, &p_tamanhoImagem, p_tamanhoImagem);

    if(imagem.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Erro ao carregar a imagem";
        imagem = QImage();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "p_imagem size: ";
        qDebug() << p_tamanhoImagem;
    }
}

QString processaImagem::caminhoImagem() const
{
    return p_caminhoImagem;
}

void processaImagem::setCaminhoImagem(const QString valor)
{
    if (valor != p_caminhoImagem)
    {
        p_caminhoImagem = valor;
        emit caminhoImagemChanged();
    }
}

QSize processaImagem::tamanhoImagem() const
{
    return p_tamanhoImagem;
}

void processaImagem::setTamanhoImagem(const QSize valor)
{
    bool alterou = false;

    if (valor.width() != p_tamanhoImagem.width())
    {
        p_tamanhoImagem.setWidth(valor.width());
        alterou = true;
    }

    if (valor.height() != p_tamanhoImagem.height())
    {
        p_tamanhoImagem.setHeight(valor.height());
        alterou = true;
    }

    if(alterou)
    {
        emit tamanhoImagemChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

In the method `processaImagem` just pass a empty QSize as parameter to the provider and it will return the image with it original size:

```
QImage processaImagem::carregaImagem()
{
    QUrl caminhoImagem(p_caminhoImagem);
    QQmlEngine *engine = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
    QQmlImageProviderBase *imageProviderBase = engine->imageProvider(caminhoImagem.host());
    QQuickImageProvider *imageProvider = static_cast<QQuickImageProvider*>(imageProviderBase);

    QSize imageSize;    
    QString imageId = caminhoImagem.path().remove(0, 1);
    QImage imagem = imageProvider->requestImage(imageId, &imageSize, imageSize);

    if(imagem.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Erro ao carregar a imagem";
        imagem = QImage();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "p_imagem size: ";
        qDebug() << p_tamanhoImagem;
    }
}
```